# CA2227: Collection properties should be read only

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Consider I have the following class in my entity models:

```
public Entity{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   ....
   public virtual ICollection<SecondEntity> SecondEntities { get; set; }
}
```

and the Dto:

```
public EntityDto{
   public int ID {get; set;}
   ....
   public virtual ICollection<SecondEntityDto> SecondEntities { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in my Data Access Layer I am using projection, so a `GetAll()` method would look like this:

```
public async Task<ICollection<EntityDto>> GetAll()
        {
            using (var context = new entityContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    return await Task.FromResult(
                     context.Entity.Select(p => new EntityDto() {
                            Id = p.Id,
                            SecondEntities = p.SecondEntities.Select(q => new SecondEntity() {
                                 Id = q.Id })
                            .ToList() })
                     .ToList());
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    log.Error("Error", ex);
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
```

But the Code Analyser is now complaining that I shouldn't have setters on my collection. If I remove the setter, I can't (or I don't know how to) populate that collection in the same call to the database. If I break this call in 2 separate calls, one to get the `Entity` and the second one to get the `Entity.SecondEntities` I will have to write more code and also make more calls to the database, plus the fact that I would have to do that in a `loop` to get the `SecondEntity` for every `Entity` object and I don't think that would be optimal in this case(well, I actually know for a fact that's a bad idea, querying the database from loops). Can anyone correct me? Or is there any other way of retrieving relational databases, project them into a Dto class and in the same time obey the rule of having my collections `readonly`?

Obviously, it's also complaining about the signature (nested generic types) but from what I've read, for 1-2 levels of nesting I should just ignore that.

P.S... I've also checked this example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327.aspx) but I don't see how that would apply to this case.

Comment: Basically, you are not meant to do this `SecondEntities =`, because this replaces the reference to the collection. What you should do instead is something like this: `SecondEntities.Clear(); SecondEntities.AddRange(..);`

Comment: But then, I would have to write a loop and do that for every `Entity` in that collection, which means that for 10.000 rows of data, 10.000 calls to the database for that `SecondEntities` which would damage the performance greatly, in stead of just getting the entire  table of data from what call.. Another better way would be not to project, but than for bigger tables it would damage the performance again... This, apparently doesn't do  any harm.. (or less  harm compared to the other 2 options)... am I wrong about this?

Comment: Why would you need a loop? In your current code there is just one

SecondEntities =

So if you provide a SetSecondEntities(ICollection<SecondEntityDto> se) method with the code oleksii has posted, you will have the same result and you can remove your setter and by the way, make the field readonly.

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2227) now states that it is reasonable to disable the warning in this case.

> You can suppress the warning if the property is part of a Data Transfer Object (DTO) class.
> Otherwise, do not suppress warnings from this rule.

There are other alternatives to consider, depending on your deserialization needs:

- include a constructor in your DTO that accepts an object and sets its properties from it
- use init setters (C# 9) as per [Update CA2227 to not report on init only property](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/pull/4463)